# Object Mappings Relationship using RestKit 0.20

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I am trying to read data from server using RestKit 0.20 in my iOS app and getting the following error :

```
//Error

`… I restkit:RKLog.m:34 RestKit logging initialized...`
`… I restkit.support:RKMIMETypeSerialization.m:115 JSON Serialization class 'RKNSJSONSerialization' detected: Registering for MIME Type 'application/json`
`... T restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:139 GET '(null)':
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en, fr, de, ja, nl, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, sv, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us;q=0.8";
    "User-Agent" = "XXXXX/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 5.0; Scale/1.00)";
}
request.body=(null)`

`... E restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:150 GET '(null)' (0):
error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x6c9d570 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6c9d460 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
response.body=(null)`
`... E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:270 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x6c9d570 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6c9d460 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}`

`... Hit error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x6c9d570 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6c9d460 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}`
```

Here is the JSON received from server:

```
[ {
    "array1" : [ {
    "a1prop1" : 1,
    "a1prop2" : "prop21val",
   }, {
     "a1prop1" : 2,
     "a1prop2" : "prop22val",
    }, {
     "a1prop1" : 3,
     "a1prop2" : "prop23val",
    } ],
  "property1" : prop1val,
  "property2" : "prop2val",
  "property3" : "prop3val",
} ]
```

Mappings using RestKit:

```
-(void) getData {
………………...
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

RKObjectMapping *array1Mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ArrayOneClass class]];
[array1Mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"a1Prop1" : @"a1Prop1",
 @"a1Prop2" : @"a1Prop2",
 }];

RKObjectMapping *mainObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MainObjectClass class]]
[mainObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"property1" : @"property1",
 @"property2" : @"property2",
 @"property3" : @"property3",
 }];

RKRelationshipMapping *mainObjRelationMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"array1" toKeyPath:@"array1" withMapping:array1Mapping];
[mainObjectMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"array1" mapping: mainObjRelationMapping.mapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mainObjectMapping pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSString *pathStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/getAllObjects"];

[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:pathStr
                     parameters:nil
                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                            NSLog(@"...success");
                        }
                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
                        }];

}
```

MainObject Class:

//MainObjectClass.h

```
    @interface MainObjectClass : NSObject{
     int property1;
     NSString * property2;
     NSString * property3;
     NSSet *array1;
    }

@property (nonatomic) int property1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * property2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * property3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *array1;

- (NSDictionary*)elementToPropertyMappings;
- (NSDictionary*)elementToRelationshipMappings;
@end
```

//MainObjectClass.m

```
@implementation MainObjectClass

@synthesize property1, property2, property3, array1;
- (NSDictionary*)elementToPropertyMappings {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"property1", @"property1",
        @"property2", @"property2",
        @"property3", @"property3",
        nil];
}
- (NSDictionary *)elementToRelationshipMappings {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"array1", @"array1",
        nil];
}
@end
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is not generating proper request? It is not hitting the server at all. I tried simple get/post methods with no relationship mappings and they all are working fine with RestKit mappings. Appreciate your views. Thanks.

Comment: The bad URL, indicates something is wrong with the URL you are posting to. Can you add to your question with some additional details regarding the URLs you are using?

Answer (score 1):

try this :- use property of `RKObjectManager`

```
objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```